# How to find what points lie in each bin of a histogram?

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I have a 2D dimensional histogram having bin size 10. I wish to know whether there is a numpy function (or any faster method) to obtain what points lie in each bin in the 2d grid. Is there a way to access the bin elements?

Comment: how did you make the histogram?

Comment: ```B = np.random.random((100,2)); H, edges = np.histogramdd(B, bins = [10]*2, density=True)```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solve your problem. However, I believe other can improve my code because I am new in python.

Create Histogram with matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
rng = np.random.RandomState(10)  # deterministic random data
a = np.hstack((rng.normal(size=100), rng.normal(loc=5, scale=2, size=1000)))
n ,bins ,patches  = plt.hist(a, bins=10)  # arguments are passed to np.histogram
plt.title("Histogram with '10' bins")

plt.show()
```

Reshape arrays and..

```
newbin =  np.repeat(np.reshape(bins,(-1, len(bins))), a.shape, axis=0)
newa = np.repeat(np.reshape(a,(len(a),-1)),len(bins),axis=1)
#index_bin = (np.where(newbin[:,0] >np.reshape(a,(1,-1))[:,0] )  )[0][0]

index_bin = (newbin>newa).argmax(axis=1).T
```

test

```
print(a[0] ,    bins)
print(index_bin[0])
```

Output

```
1.331586504129518 [-2.13171211 -0.88255884  0.36659444  1.61574771  2.86490098  4.11405425
  5.36320753  6.6123608   7.86151407  9.11066734 10.35982062]
3
```